# QUANTEDA - invalid class “dfmSparse” object

Tags: r, quanteda

I get this warning-message. I use these data:

https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda/tree/master/data/data_char_inaugural.RData

RStudio version: Version 1.0.136 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.

```
 library(quanteda)
 uk2010immigCorpus <- corpus(data_char_ukimmig2010, docvars = data.frame(party = names(data_char_ukimmig2010)),metacorpus = list(notes = "Immigration-related sections of 2010 UK party manifestos"))
 mydfm <- dfm(uk2010immigCorpus, remove = c("will", stopwords("english")),removePunct = TRUE)


 Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “dfmSparse” object: superclass "replValueSp" not defined in the environment of the object's class
```

What's wrong with QUANTEDA?

Thanks!
majesus

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `sessionInfo()`: `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8   LC_NUMERIC=C   LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8  LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8  LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C LC_ADDRESS=C  LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C  
attached base packages:
[1] stats   graphics grDevices utils datasets  methods   base  
other attached packages:
[1] quanteda_0.9.9-17`

Comment: `loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Matrix_1.2-7.1 tools_3.3.2  fastmatch_1.1-0 Rcpp_0.12.9  stringi_1.1.2 grid_3.3.2 data.table_1.10.0
 [8] RcppParallel_4.3.20 lattice_0.20-34  ca_0.70`

Comment: Yes it seemed to be an issue with your version of the *Matrix* package. Always best to make sure your packages and R version are up to date. We need some of the newer functions in *Matrix* to make the sparse object handling work.

Comment: And in the future, this sort of qn is better for an issue on GitHub than SO.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. Your response and advice have been helpful. In the future I will use the channel you suggest me, for my doubts about Quanteda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing Matrix library and then reinstalling quanteda, finally I reboot R and now dfm works.

```
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("quanteda")
```

Comment: Thanks for the speed in your answer. I installed Matrix, uninstalled Quanteda, I installed it again, and I restarted R. All great.