# Minimal number of coverage of lists

Tags: r, list

I have the following:

```
dist<-c('att1','att2','att3','att4','att5','att6')
p1<-c('att1','att5','att2')
p2<-c('att5','att1','att4')
p3<-c('att3','att4','att2')
p4<-c('att1','att2','att3')
p5<-c('att6')
```

I would like to find all the relevant `p` that the unification of them will be the maximal components of `dist`. 
I this case the solution would be `p1, p3, p5`. 
I want to choose the minimal number of `p`. In addition, in case there is no way to cover all the of dist component so I want to choose the maximal cover.

Comment: Why only `p1, p3, p5`? Isn't `p2, p3, p5` also the same?

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, you are right. In this case since p1 and p2 have the same number of attributes it can be also a solution. For me one solution is good enough (I don't have to get all of them) only the first ones who meet the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempted solution. I've tried as much I can to vectorize/matricize hope it's fast enough. Each step is explained in the comment

```
library(qdapTools)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
## generate matrix of attributes
grid_matrix <- do.call(CJ, rep(list(1:0), 5))  %>% as.matrix
attribute_matrix
##   att1 att2 att3 att4 att5 att6
## 1    1    1    0    0    1    0
## 2    1    0    0    1    1    0
## 3    0    1    1    1    0    0
## 4    1    1    1    0    0    0
## 5    0    0    0    0    0    1

## create a grid of combination of matrix
grid_matrix <- do.call(CJ, rep(list(1:0), 5))  %>% as.matrix
colnames(grid_matrix) <- paste0("p", 1:5)

## check whether each combination has all attribute presented
combin_all_element_present <- rowSums(grid_matrix %*% attribute_matrix > 0) %>% 
  `==`(., ncol(attribute_matrix))

combin_all_element_present
##  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [12] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

## generate a submatrix which satisfy the condition
grid_matrix_sub <- grid_matrix[combin_all_element_present, ]
## find the combinations with minumun number of p
grid_matrix_sub[rowSums(grid_matrix_sub) == min(rowSums(grid_matrix_sub)), ]
##      p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
## [1,]  0  1  0  1  1
## [2,]  0  1  1  0  1
## [3,]  1  0  1  0  1
```

**Note**

In case you want to use quanteda, you can generate `attribute_matrix` with

```
library(quanteda)
attribute_matrix <- lapply(list(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5), function(x) paste(x, collapse = ' ')) %>% 
  unlist %>% tokens %>% dfm %>% as.matrix
attribute_matrix
##        features
## docs    att1 att5 att2 att4 att3 att6
##   text1    1    1    1    0    0    0
##   text2    1    1    0    1    0    0
##   text3    0    0    1    1    1    0
##   text4    1    0    1    0    1    0
##   text5    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: Thanks I get the following error:> attribute_matrix <- lapply(list(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5), function(x) paste(x, collapse = ' ')) %>% 
+     unlist %>% tokens %>% dfm %>% as.matrix
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “dfmSparse” object: superclass "replValueSp" not defined in the environment of the object's class

Comment: Hmm. It should be a version issue of `quanteda`. What's your version?

Comment: > packageVersion("quanteda")
[1] ‘0.9.9.65’ . I installed the Matrix package and now my error is Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “dfmSparse” object: superclass "replValueSp" not defined in the environment of the object's class

Comment: Could you restart session, reinstall `quanteda`, and run the code? It seems a known issue for quanteda...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025827/quanteda-invalid-class-dfmsparse-object

Comment: Done and still does not work, same error. Is there an alternative to the line?

Comment: I will think about it

Comment: See my update. I am not really familiar with `qdapTools` but the output is the same.

Comment: Thanks it works! So practically I can choose grid_matrix_sub first row if I want only the first solution?

Comment: Yes. That's right. You can pick any one row from the outcome matrix.

Comment: `data.table::CJ` perhaps but this operation is always an expensive one.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know. Is this efficient? `do.call(CJ, list(0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1))`

Comment: I get an error: > combin_all_element_present <- rowSums(grid_matrix %*% attribute_matrix > 0) %>% 
+   `==`(., ncol(attribute_matrix))
Error in grid_matrix %*% attribute_matrix : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Comment: I get the following error: grid_matrix <- do.call(CJ, rep(list(1:0), N))  %>% as.matrix
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.0 Gb
I work with N=32 and can be much bigger. How can I work with this big data?

Comment: The first thing I would try is to restrict the matrix with the known minimum number of row sums in each time when `CJ` is called. For example, if you know that there is a combination of 10 `p`s which satisfy the maximum coverage, all you need is to have a matrix with the maximum row sums of 9.   If this still doesn't work, another possibility is to create a matrix with constant row sums and increment the number. For instance, create a matrix with all row sums == 2. If there is not a combination in this matrix increment the row sums until you find the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please show an example of how to do it? Since my number of p can be very big (1024)?

Comment: If the number of p can be that big, there has to be very different solution for the problem. For N = 1024, the combination you can explore with one matrix is 3, and I assume that cannot be a solution. I would recommend opening a new question stating that you need a large data solution. If you still need smaller combination solution, I can work on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @amatsuo_net, I would like to ask one more little question. Can I open a discussion in chat?

Comment: Yes. You can convert this entire discussion to chat.