# Minimal number of coverage of big data lists

Tags: r, list, vector, bigdata

Following my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612937/minimal-number-of-coverage-of-lists/44614341#44614341) 
I use the following code:

```
dist<-c('att1','att2','att3','att4','att5','att6')
p1<-c('att1','att5','att2')
p2<-c('att5','att1','att4')
p3<-c('att3','att4','att2')
p4<-c('att1','att2','att3')
p5<-c('att6')
....
p32<-c('att35','att34','att32')
```

In the real case there can be 1024 vectors.
I would like to find all the relevant `p` that the unification of them will be the maximal components of dist. I this case the solution would be `p1`, `p3`, `p5`. I want to choose the minimal number of `p`. In addition, in case there is no way to cover all the of dist component so I want to choose the maximal cover with minimal number of vectors (p).

```
N = 32
library(qdapTools)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
## generate matrix of attributes
attribute_matrix <- mtabulate(list(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5,...,p32))

library (bigmemory)
## generate matrix of attributes
grid_matrix <- do.call(CJ, rep(list(1:0), N))  %>% as.big.matrix

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.0 Gb
```

I tried an alternative way for it:

```
grid_matrix <- do.call(CJ, rep(list(1:0), N))  %>% as.data.frame
grid_matrix <- as.matrix (grid_matrix)
```

And still got the same error.

How can I fix it and use it for big data? I wanted to continue with:

```
 colnames(grid_matrix) <- paste0("p", 1:N)
    combin_all_element_present <- rowSums(grid_matrix %*% attribute_matrix > 0) %>% `==`(., ncol(attribute_matrix))
    grid_matrix_sub <- grid_matrix[combin_all_element_present, ]
    grid_matrix_sub[rowSums(grid_matrix_sub) == min(rowSums(grid_matrix_sub)), ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a set covering problem.  It can be solved using integer linear programming.  Let x1, x2, ... be 0/1 variables (one for each p variable) and represent p1, p2, ... as 0/1 vectors P1, P2, ... and dist as
a 0/1 vector D.  Then the problem can be stated as:

```
min x1 + x2 + ... + x32
such that
P1 * x1 + P2 + x2 + ... + P32 * x32 >= D
```

which in R code is the following. First create a list `p` with the p vectors in sorted order.  Use `mixedsort` so that p32 comes at the end instead of rigth after p3.  Define `attnames` as the set of all att names in all the p vectors. 
 Then formulate the objective function (which equals the number of p's in the cover), the constraint matrix (consisting of the P vectors as columns) and the right hand side of the constraint equations (which is dist as a 0/1 vector).  Finally run the integer linear program and convert the solution from a 0/1 vector to a vector of p names.

```
library(gtools)
library(lpSolve)

p <- mget(mixedsort(ls(pattern = "^p\\d+$")))
attnames <- mixedsort(unique(unlist(p)))
objective <- rep(1L, length(p))
const.mat <- sapply(p, function(x) attnames %in% x) + 0L
const.rhs <- (attnames %in% dist) + 0L

ans <- lp("min", objective, const.mat, ">=", const.rhs, all.bin = TRUE)
names(p)[ans$solution == 1L]
## [1] "p2" "p4" "p5"
```

The constraint matrix has a row for each `attnames` entry and a column for each `p` vector.

The solution produces the minimal covers of those `attnames` elements that are in `dist`.  If every element of `dist` appears in at least one `p` vector then the solution will represent a cover of `dist`.  If not, the solution will represent a cover of those att names in one or more `p` vectors that are also in `dist`; thus, this handles both cases discussed in the question.  The uncovered elements of `dist` are:

```
setdiff(dist, attnames)
```

so if that is of zero length then the solution represents a complete cover of `dist`.  If not the solution represents a cover of

```
intersect(dist, attnames)
```

The sorting done in the code is not stricly needed but it may be easier to work with the various inputs to the optimization by having the rows and columns of the constraint matrix in a logical order.

**Note:** Run this code from the question before running the above code:

```
dist<-c('att1','att2','att3','att4','att5','att6')
p1<-c('att1','att5','att2')
p2<-c('att5','att1','att4')
p3<-c('att3','att4','att2')
p4<-c('att1','att2','att3')
p5<-c('att6')
p32<-c('att35','att34','att32')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @G. Grothendieck! I would like to ask: (1) Does using the mixedsort mean that each vector number will be after the vector number before (i.e. p1,p2,p3,p4...,p31,p32)? (2) If there is no optimal solution, I would like to get the maximal cover, but not the full cover does the code support it? and finally, is it the most efficient way to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks again! I get an error: > const.mat <- sapply(p, function(x) attnames %in% x) + 0L
 Error in attnames %in% x : object 'attnames' not found
In addition if I have a list called nam which all the vectors are in there (from 1 to 32 i.e. nam[[1]]..nam[[32]]) Do I have to change: p <- mget(mixedsort(ls(nam))?
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in attnames %in% x : object 'attnames' not found
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in attnames %in% x : object 'attnames' not found

Comment: If I have instead of p a list that contains all the p i.e. list called nam that nam[[1]] is p1... nam[[32]] is p32 do I have to change the line into
p <- mget(mixedsort(ls(nam)))?

Comment: When I enter the value of list in p such as: > head (nam)
[[1]]
 [1] "V2"  "V13" "V6"  "V12" "V17" "V4"  "V5"  "V16" "V14" "V11" "V3"  "V7"  "V9" 

[[2]]
 [1] "V9"  "V14" "V10" "V13" "V12" "V16" "V4"  "V2"  "V7"  "V5"  "V11" "V6" 

[[3]]
 [1] "V7"  "V9"  "V2"  "V5"  "V12" "V14" "V17" "V15" "V8"  "V6"  "V16" "V10" "V3"  "V4"  "V13"

[[4]]
 [1] "V10" "V3"  "V11" "V4"  "V13" "V8"  "V2"  "V17" "V14" "V16" "V6"  "V5"  "V12" "V9" 

[[5]]
 [1] "V16" "V3"  "V14" "V12" "V2"  "V6"  "V13" "V15" "V10" "V9"  "V5"  "V8"
I get > names(p)[ans$solution == 1L]
character(0)

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck, I have a list called 'nam' (it is same as p). What do I have to insert to 'p' or to the code to work on the contents of 'nam'
> str (nam)
List of 31
 $ : chr [1:13] "V2" "V13" "V6" "V12" ...
 $ : chr [1:12] "V9" "V14" "V10" "V13" ...
 $ : chr [1:15] "V7" "V9" "V2" "V5" ...
 $ : chr [1:14] "V10" "V3" "V11" "V4" ...
 $ : chr [1:12] "V16" "V3" "V14" "V12" ..

Comment: It's likely you just have to set p <- nam instead of the p <- ... line in the answer.  Of course dist would have to be defined in terms of V instead of att to be consistent.

Comment: I get > names(p)[ans$solution == 1L]
[1] "" where I used dist<-colnames(....) and p <- nam instead of p <- mget(mixedsort(ls(pattern = "^p\\d+$"))). You can see that > dist
 [1] "V2"  "V3"  "V4"  "V5"  "V6"  "V7"  "V8"  "V9"  "V10" "V11" "V12" "V13" "V14" "V15" "V16" "V17"  > str (dist)
 chr [1:16] "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6" "V7" "V8" "V9" "V10" "V11" "V12" "V13" "V14" "V15" ...
> class (dist)
[1] "character"   and nam is as described above, Why is it?

Comment: I can't really read this. If you can provide a reproducible example legibly formatted that I can copy and paste into R then I might be able to respond.

Comment: In pleasure. Can I send you via email or chat?

Comment: None of your attnames are in dist so the correct solution as a 0/1 vector is all zeros which is what you got.

Comment: The solution down here works for it. I saw difference in the names of the matrix. The nam does not have names for each vector while p (in the source example) does have for each row (vector). Might this be the reason?

Comment: Your `p` has no names but you are referring to `names(p)` in the last line of code.  Use the 0/1 vector `ans$solution` as your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer already provided is perfect but another approach could be the following:

```
dist<-c('att1','att2','att3','att4','att5','att6')
p1<-c('att1','att5','att2')
p2<-c('att5','att1','att4')
p3<-c('att3','att4','att2')
p4<-c('att1','att2','att3')
p5<-c('att6')


library(qdapTools)
library(data.table)
attribute_matrix <- mtabulate(list(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5))


minimal_sets <- function(superset, subsets_matrix, p){

  setDT(subsets_matrix)
  # removing the columns that are not in the superset
  updated_sub_matr <- subsets_matrix[, which(names(subsets_matrix) %in% superset), with = F]

  # initializing counter for iterations and the subset selected 
  subset_selected <- integer(0)
  counter <- p

  ## Loop until either we ran out of iterations counter = 0 or we found the solution
  while (counter > 0 & length(superset) > 0){

    ## find the row with the most matches with the superset we want to achieve  
    max_index <- which.max(rowSums(updated_sub_matr))

    ## remove from the superset the entries that match that line and from the subsets_matrix those columns as they dont contribute anymore
    superset <- superset[which(updated_sub_matr[max_index, ] == 0)]
    updated_sub_matr <- updated_sub_matr[, - which(updated_sub_matr[max_index, ] != 0), with = F]

    counter <- counter - 1
    subset_selected <- c(subset_selected, max_index)
  }

  if (length(superset) > 0){
    print(paste0("No solution found, there are(is) ", length(superset), " element(s) left ", paste(superset, collapse = "-")))            
  } else {            
    print(paste0("Found a solution after ", p - counter, " iterations"))           
  }

  print(paste0("Selected the following subsets: ", paste(subset_selected, collapse = "-")))

}
```

In this function you input your superset (in this case dist), the attribute_matrix and the number p which you want to check and it outputs the best possible solution it found as well as the iterations.

```
> minimal_sets(dist, attribute_matrix, 1)
[1] "No solution found, there are(is) 3 element(s) left att3-att4-att6"
[1] "Selected the following subsets: 1"

> minimal_sets(dist, attribute_matrix, 3)
[1] "Found a solution after 3 iterations"
[1] "Selected the following subsets: 1-3-5"

> minimal_sets(dist, attribute_matrix, 5)
[1] "Found a solution after 3 iterations"
[1] "Selected the following subsets: 1-3-5
```